# Ruby min function not selecting the shortest string

Tags: ruby, string

I don't understand why `min` is selecting the longest string instead of the shortest:

```
x='AGG'
y='AAAACTGACCCACCCCAGG'
[x,y].min #=> "AAAACTGACCCACCCCAGG" # why is this the min one?
[x,y].max #=> "AGG"

a='AGAGACTTA'
b='AAA'
[b,a].min #=> "AAA" # good
[b,a].max #=> "AGAGACTTA"
```

Comment: The answer to your question is in the docs for [String#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). Similarly, for ordering array, see [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). Also, have a read of the docs for Ruby's [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html) module.

Comment: If two strings have equal length, what should your code do? Do you need them ordered alphabetically then, or is length only important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Ruby uses something called [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) to get minimum and maximum string. Therefore `AGG > AAAACTGACCCACCCCAGG`, because `G > A` (first letter they differ in).

To get your expected behaviour you need to manually provided comparator block, like this:

```
[x,y].min { |x,y| x.size <=> y.size }
```

Comment: Even that isn't sufficient if the sizes are the same. Then you should look at the lexicographical ordering in addition.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what expected behaviour is in that case - sorting in Ruby is stable, so if size is same min will return first provided in array.

Comment: Sorting in Ruby is not stable.

Comment: Please, use `min_by` in this case. It's much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not comparing by string length, but by lexicographical ordering; and `AA` comes before `AG`. If you want to compare by length, you need to specify it:

```
p [x,y].min_by(&:length)
```

Comment: `length` isn't all that needs to be considered if they're the same length. You'll need to also sort lexicographically in that case.

Comment: @theTinMan: "need"? No. You need to do what is sufficient for the task, and the task as described only says "shortest". If someone tells you to bake a cake, you bake a cake, don't invent the whole banquet just in case. It could be that the secondary sort key is unnecesary and speed matters, it could be that the secondary key would be reverse lexicographical, or it could be an external ordering by another field altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's min function sorts by whether a string is greater than another one. In this case String Y occurs earlier in the alphabet than string X, therefore it's less than string X. If you want to find which is the shortest string you could do something like.

```
[x,y].min_by(&:length)
=> "AGG"
```

To find the longest string you would do

```
[x,y].max_by(&:length)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that min/max doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't compare string sizes, just gives you the first one in alphabetic order.
Luckily, min / max functions allow you to define how to check which object is bigger. Try something like:

```
arr.min {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}
arr.max {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}
```

Comment: Please, use `min_by` in this case. It's much easier to understand.